# Grails redirects to wrong address when using app.context?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, grails, groovy

I'm noticing some odd behavior with `redirect` when I set my `app.context` a certain way.  I found a bug in the Grails JIRA which describes my problem perfectly, but it was marked as UTR: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7546

**Here is my description of the problem:**
I'm currently using Grails 2.0M2.  I have the following properties defined in my application.properties file:

```
app.context=/
app.name=foobar
```

When I call `redirect` in a controller, `redirect` is adding the app name onto the uri I provide, which then causes a 404.  Here is how I'm doing this:

```
String partialUrl = createLink(mapping: 'helloworld') // returns `/hello/world`
redirect(uri: partialUrl) // INCORRECTLY redirects to 
                          // `http://mysite.com/foobar/hello/world`
                          // instead of `http://mysite.com/hello/world`
```

Assume that I have a URL mapping named `helloworld` defined in my `UrlMappings.groovy` file with a path of `/hello/world`.

So, long story short, if I set the `app.context` to `/`, I would **NOT** expect the `app.name` to show up in my final redirect URL.

Is this a bug or expected behavior?  Any idea on the easiest way I could build up the redirect URL without doing too many manual steps?

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it, but I cannot reproduce it either. I created a test project with one controller (named Hello), using your code to create an action that does nothing but redirect:

## HelloController.groovy

```
package test1

class HelloController {
   def index() {
      def model = [:]
      model.content = 'content...'
      model
   }

   def redir() {
      String partialUrl = createLink(mapping: 'helloworld') // returns `/hello/world`
      redirect(uri: partialUrl) // INCORRECTLY redirects to 
                            // `http://mysite.com/foobar/hello/world`
                            // instead of `http://mysite.com/hello/world`
   }
}
```

I created an index page, index.gsp in the views/hello

## index.gsp

```
<h1>index.gsp</h1>
<html>
   <body>
      <p>This data is coming from the model:</p>
      <p>content: ${content}</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Setup helloworld in the UrlMappings to map to the index action of the hello controller:

## UrlMappings.groovy

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/helloworld"(controller: "hello", action: "index")

        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

And changed the application.properties to have the app.context=/

## application.properties

```
#Grails Metadata file
#Sun Nov 06 14:51:56 EST 2011
app.grails.version=2.0.0.RC1
app.context=/
app.name=test1
app.servlet.version=2.5
app.version=0.1
```

When I ran the app, I could go to localhost:8080/hello and it would show my simple GSP. I tried localhost:8080/helloworld and also got it as expected per the mapping. Then I tried localhost:8080/hello/redir and I was properly redirected to localhost:8080/helloworld.

However, if you're still facing this issue, I have a few suggestions
1) Try using the new link generator available in 2.0 instead of createLink. It may not do anything different, but worth a try: `grailsLinkGenerator.link(mapping: 'helloworld')`
2) If it's only on redirects from within controllers, you could just add the http://mysite.com portion yourself to the partialUrl.
3) Last resort, write a Filter attached to afterView that does a regex search and replace on the contents for mysite.com/foobar. Not sure this will catch redirects though, but if anything would, I'd assume this would be it since filters can be applied at broad level.

Answer (score 1):

```
  def yourAction = {

       redirect(uri:"helloworld")

  }
```

That doesnt work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct anwser to your question but my practice is : I never modify app.context in the grails properties since tomcat override it on production and I don't care which context it uses on my dev.

Comment: Right... Tomcat might override app.context in production, however the issue still remains that `redirect` that Grails is using the app.name when building redirect URLs instead of using app.context.